# Cannot save a Keras model, is this a bug?

Tags: keras, save, resnet

I'm trying to do a simple save of a resnet50 model and I'm getting an error. My code to reproduce the error:

```
from tensorflow import keras
import keras_resnet

inputs = keras.layers.Input(shape=(None, None, 3))
resnet = keras_resnet.models.ResNet50(inputs, include_top=False, freeze_bn=True)

resnet.save("my-model")
```

I get the error: "KeyError: 'inputs'". Is this a bug or is there something I'm missing with the keras save command? I tried the command on MacOS and in my ubuntu container. Same result.

EDIT: it's working with the official keras implementation of resnet. With this implementation though I have to change the code in resnet.py file of fizyr implementation of keras-retinanet. Specifically, having defined resnet with:

```
from keras.applications.resnet import ResNet50,ResNet101,ResNet152
resnet = ResNet50(input_tensor=inputs, include_top=False)
```

I have to change the code of the backbone layers from :

```
backbone_layers = {
    'C2': resnet.outputs[0],
    'C3': resnet.outputs[1],
    'C4': resnet.outputs[2],
    'C5': resnet.outputs[3]
}
```

to:

```
backbone_layers = {
    'C2': resnet.layers[-137].output,
    'C3': resnet.layers[-95].output,
    'C4': resnet.layers[-33].output,
    'C5': resnet.outputs[0]
}
```

I didn't test it yet but I think it should work.

The only caveat I see is that I don't have the freeze_bn parameter anymore. See https://github.com/fizyr/keras-retinanet/issues/974 for the reason of this parameter. I hope it will not adversely affect the training of my network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the model with a format, e.g. h5.
I reproduced your error, fixed it with:

`resnet.save("mymodel.h5")`

Comment: also potentially review the install, as discussed here: https://github.com/fizyr/keras-retinanet/issues/530

Comment: but I don't want h5 format, I need SavedModel format

Comment: As you instantiate the model with keras_resnet, you should use the "old" keras saving format. If you want to use the Tensorflow SaveModel format, then instantiate your model from there - https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications/ResNet50

Comment: At least that's how I interpret this error without looking too deep in the keras_resnet doc

Comment: That's what I was testing and it's working with the TF implementation. As I am working with the keras-retinanet implementation of fizyr, I also have to change some code, specifically in resnet.py file. I'll edit my post to reflect the changes.